# UIbutton width and high zero?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have this

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
              action:@selector(myAction:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Action", @"")
           forState:UIControlStateNormal];
CGFloat width = button.bounds.size.width;
```

at this point width is zero...

zero?

any clues why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `sizeToFit` on your button after setting the title label. This will size it appropriately to the text you have just set.

This gets called anyway on the button before it is drawn, but since you seem to need it earlier, you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 7):

As you have not set the frame of UIButton, modify the code as

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(20,20,50,50);
[button addTarget:self
              action:@selector(myAction:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Action", @"")
           forState:UIControlStateNormal];
CGFloat width = button.bounds.size.width; // Now the width of button would be 50
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a button but you are not setting its frame, either create it using interface builder and access its frame after the view its loaded, or give it a frame like:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setFrame: CGRectMake (100, 200, 150, 44)];
[button addTarget:self ....
```